# Grails 2.2.3 dependency issue not resolving

Tags: grails

I am using grails 2.2.3 with java 1.7_40
each time i clean or build i get this

> : asm#asm;3.3.1: configuration not found in asm#asm;3.3.1: 'compile'. It was required from org.apache.cxf#cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws;2.6.2 compile

Comment: Try `clean` then `refresh-dependencies`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Cleaned grails cache.
2. Clean and build.
3.Refresh Dependencies

did this like hundred times.

Comment: Try  running `dependency-report`